# Change last octet of IP address

Tags: python-2.7, ip-address

With the below code I fetch the IP address from a text file which contains list of IP addresses. Then SSH into Cisco Router to make changes that is common to all the devices. This time however I have to make changes that are variable in nature.

**Example:**

I have to fetch the ip address (10.120.15.1) and SSH into the device and apply the following command

"access-list 150 permit ip **10.120.15.0** 0.0.0.255 host 10.100.100.1"

The IP address is already contained in the variable "line" and I have to split the last octet and change it from "1" to "0" and then insert to the access list.

Please share your inputs.

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os
import time
import cmd

buff = ''
resp = ''

with open('Address.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        dssh.connect(line, username='cisco', password='cisco')
        chan = dssh.invoke_shell()
        chan.send('conf t\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        resp = chan.recv(9999)
        chan.send('access-list 150 permit ip X.X.X.X 0.0.0.255 host 10.100.100.1\n exit\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        resp = chan.recv(9999) 
 dssh.close()
```

Comment: There is an [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress.html) module, but it was introduced in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`netaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) Python package.

Example:

```
>>> n = IPNetwork('10.120.15.1/24')
>>> list(n)[0:3]
[IPAddress('10.120.15.0'), IPAddress('10.120.15.1'), IPAddress('10.120.15.2')]
>>> IPNetwork('10.120.15.1/24').network
IPAddress('10.120.15.0')
>>> str(IPNetwork('10.120.15.1/24').network)
'10.120.15.0'
```

As for your script, you should be able to perform all of the access list modifications in the same SSH session, rather than one SSH session per address line.

I also suspect that you have inverted the netmask in your `access-list` command — it should probably be `255.255.255.0` rather than `0.0.0.255` (see [examples](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/interfaces-modules/catalyst-6500-series-firewall-services-module/98591-fwsm-basic-config.html)).

Furthermore, I see that you are generating many access rules of the same form. That will be difficult to manage. Instead, you should write one access rule that references a network object group. You should only use your script to add/remove members of the group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe you have understood my query wrongly. My task here is to change the last octet of the IP address from "1" to "0" and insert it to the access list.                                                Ex: IP address is 10.120.15.1;                                  Change the IP address to 10.120.15.0 then insert the converted IP address in the access list in place of X.X.X.X;                access-list 150 permit ip X.X.X.X 0.0.0.255 host 10.100.100.1;            Final output is = access-list 150 permit ip 10.120.15.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.100.100.1.

Comment: That's what the example above does. You just have to incorporate it into your script as `str(IPNetwork(line.strip() + '/24').network)`.